# Embed HTML inside JSON request body in ServiceStack

Tags: json, servicestack

I've been working with ServiceStack for a while now and recently a new need came up that requires receiving of some html templates inside a JSON request body. I'm obviously thinking about escaping this HTML and it seems to work but I would prefer consumers not to bother escaping a potentially large template. I know ASP.NET is capable of handling this but I wonder if it can be done with ServiceStack.

The following JSON body is received incomplete at the REST endpoint because of the second double quote ...="test...

```
{
   "template" : "<html><body><div name="test"></div></body></html>"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> "I would prefer consumers not to bother escaping a potentially large template"

I'm not sure I follow.  Why would the consumers know anything about escaping a template?  Shouldn't that be transparent to the consumer?  Any call to `JSON.stringify(sourceString)` or `sourceString.toJson()` will automatically escape embedded double-quotes.

> "I know ASP.NET is capable of handling this"

Embedded double-quotes must be escaped in valid json syntax.  I don't see how ASP.NET wouldn't have the same problem.  Am I missing something?